# Flutter internet permission for desktop app? all packages are supported for desktop app or different packages for desktop?

Tags: flutter

I want to develop one app for desktop, so all packages are same for desktop? and how to give internet permission for desktop.

All packages which are available for flutter developing that package works for desktop app?